# Android emulator tear down during tests run

Tags: selenium, android-emulator, appium, appium-android, selenide

guys!
I run my Android tests with Appium on Android emulator. Where I run my tests in sequence emulator sometimes tear down and remaining tests are ignored.

In Appium logs i see this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell settings delete global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps' exited with code 20'; Stderr: 'cmd: Can't find service: settings'; Code: '20'
```

Is there anybody face with such problem?

Comment: check your capabilities. Perhaps, there are no installed application on emulator.

Comment: With caps everything ok. When I run tests sometimes everything good, sometimes I get that error.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run an adb-shell command which is not allowed.

Appium has some in-secure commands that normally it will not allow them to be used.

You can see the commands here: [Appium Insecure Features](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/security/)

The `adb-shell` commands (to change the system settings) is one of them.

Follow the link to how to prevent appium checking this.

**How to resolve:**

At the beginning of test setup, run this commnad: `appium --relaxed-security` with command line. Then the appium let you using the insecure feautures during the test.
for example in pyhton you should run `os.system(appium --relaxed-security` (while having appium directory in the system environment variables path.